# Remote Command execution over ssh occasionally returns command not found

Tags: ssh

I'm executing a command over ssh:

```
ssh user@ip sudo /var/app/custom
```

Occasionally, around 10% of the time, this fails with

> ```
> sudo: /var/app/custom: command not found
> Remote command failed with exit status 1
> ```

I can pre-`ssh` to the box and look the command is 100% present at `/var/app/custom` (which is a symfony php command) and this is not a consistent issue.

The application is on the local root filesystem (no NFS or Samba involved).

output for `ssh user@ip stat /var/app/custom`:

```
Size: 843           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: ca01h/51713d    Inode: 1596471     Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1001/username)   Gid: ( 
1001/username)
Access: 2022-09-20 16:52:55.860715830 +0000
Modify: 2022-09-15 20:59:12.000000000 +0000
Change: 2022-09-20 16:52:51.300861557 +0000
Birth: -
```

output for `ssh user@ip mount` (truncated, believe this is the relevant bit)

```
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try executing: `ssh user@ip 'sudo /var/app/custom || ls -l /var/app/custom'` until you get a failure.  Then [edit] your post to show the output returned from that command.

Comment: @JimL. Unfortunately this runs against a box that spawns a long running command on a schedule. Im not 100% sure the job is idempotent, but I can update the task running going forward to see what I can see from that. Thanks